# Calculate the change in the helium's energy content a process

Tags: thermodynamics

> Imagine some helium in a cylinder with an initial volume of 1 liter
>   ant initial pressure of 1 atm. Somehow the helium is made to expand to
>   a final volume of 3 liters, in such a way that its pressure rises in
>   direct proportion to its volume. Calculate the work done on the gas
>   during this process, assuming there are no other types of work being
>   done.
>
> **a)** Calculate the work done by on the gas during this process, assuming
>   that there are no other types of work being done.
>
> **b)** Calculate the change in the helium's energy content during this
>   process.
>
> **c)** Calculate the amount of heat added to or removed from helium during
>   this process.

So **a)** has already been dealt with [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501087/unit-confusion-how-pressure-and-volume-combines-to-joule/501122#501122).

**b)** The total change in energy is given by $$\Delta U = Q+W\tag1$$ where $Q$ is heat energy and $W$ is work done on the system. $W=-405 \ \text{J}$ is already given by the answer to question a), but how do I get the heat energy $Q?$

My first thought was that we can first compute $T_1$ when $P_1=1 \ \text{atm}$ and $V_1= 1 \ \text{L}$ and then compute $T_2$ at $P_2=3 \ \text{atm}$, $V_2=3 \ \text{L}$, assuming a proportionality constant of $c=1$. Now I get the two temperatures $T_1=273 \ \text{K}$ and $T_2=2457 \ \text{K}$. So the difference between these temperatures is the added energy, how do I get it in Joules and is this method correct?

**c)** I feel like this question needs to be answered in order to be used in **b)**, because in **b)**, the quantity $Q$ is what I need, right?

Comment: You can't get temperature from the information provided--you'd need to know how much helium is in the cylinder to do that.  But you can get the right answer to (b) by the method you suggested; you could assume any value for $T_1$ and get the same result.

Comment: But we already know that we have 1 liter of Helium?

Comment: That is the volume.  But you could have one liter at a temperature of 100K or 1000K and still have a pressure of 1 atm.  Just have to change the amount of gas (number of helium atoms).

Comment: Concerning the initial temperature, is it possible that the question was intended to mean that the cylinder starts out at room temperature but forgot to mention that?

Comment: @SamuelWeir - Nope. I got it from this book, chek pdf-page 32. Question 1.31. http://islamabad-institute.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/1/0/13101414/schroeder_daniel_thermal_physics.pdf

Comment: @Parseval I see the problem statement in the book, but not the solution. On what page is the book's solution. I still think the problem statement is faulty. You can assume an initial temp like you did and then get $\Delta U$, but there is no description of the process  that obeys the ideal gas law, so how do you get $W$ and $Q$, since $\Delta U=Q-W$?

Comment: @BobD - There is no solutions section in the book. The answers are in the course homepage posted by the professor. I see your point. Maybe this will shed some light: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501087/unit-confusion-how-pressure-and-volume-combines-to-joule/501122#501122

Comment: @Parseval Which part of the link should shed some light?

Comment: @BobD Was just thinking that you did not see how I found $W$ and I just wanted to show how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You analyzed it correctly, and determined the final temperature correctly.  Now just use $\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T$.  You calculate the number of moles n from the initial condition.

Comment: You can’t get temperature from information given.

Comment: This actually gives me the correct answer! But doesn't the formula you provided mean the process is Isobaric? Clearly, according to the problem the pressure varies. How can I explain this?

Comment: @Ben51 - Since we are only interested in $\Delta T$ we can assume whatever first initial conditions. So it does work.

Comment: Chet, do you agree with Parseval that you can just assume any initial temperature? Even if that can give you the internal energy change, it doesn't tell me what W or Q are since the process is not, in my opinion, clearly stated. It says pressure "rises" in proportion with volume. That implies a linear path- how do we get that for an ideal gas? To me, we  don't know the path, we don't know the mass/moles, we only know the end points. What am I missing here? How do we get work and heat?

Comment: @Parseval Chet's equation applies to any ideal gas, any process.

Comment: @BobD - The work can be calculated as per my previous post, check the link I provided above. For b) first assume STP, 273K and 1 atm. One can get the number of moles in 1 liter by 1/22.4 moles. Now we can compute $T2$ by $T_2=\frac{P_2V_2}{Nk}$ by the gaslaw $PV=NkT$ where $N=n\cdot N_A$ and $N_A$ is Avogadros number. Having T1 and T2 we can now get $\Delta T$ and obtain $\Delta U.$

Comment: @Parseval I feel your  previous post was not correct in calculating the work done because it is based on a faulty assumption, that the pressure of an ideal gas varies can vary linearly with volume. I showed you that based on the ideal gas law that cannot be correct. The only think we know are the initial and final volumes and pressures. We have not been given any valid path. I proposed in my answer to your previous post a series of constant pressure and volume paths from which you can obtain the an average value of work.

Comment: @Parseval You can assume the initial temperature and get change in internal energy. But that doesn't tell you which part of the change is due to work and which part due to heat.

Comment: @BobD -  I agree with you that it can't vary linearly in reality, however they ask us to assume something that is not true in general I guess, so we ought to do calculations based on this faulty assumption.

Comment: @Parseval You don't have a problem with that? In any event, I revised the end of my answer to acknowledge you can determine the change in internal energy with assuming an initial temperature. But that still leaves open the question of how much is work and heat. BTW, if the assumption given is faulty, why not make an assumption that can work. That was the basis of my answer to your original post. In any case, thanks for listening (the site is starting to complain about our lengthy comments!)

Comment: @BobD - No worries man! Thanks a lot for your input! I did not think at all about the faulty assumption until you pointed it out. I'm going to point this out to my prof tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Parseval Great, can you let  us know what he/she says? It  might help answer some questions.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll remember to do so!

Comment: As @BobD indicated, the internal energy of an ideal gas is a function only of temperature, irrespective of how the pressure or volume are varying; and the relationship between internal energy and temperature is always given by the equation which BobD and I wrote down.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes I agree. What I don't agree with is how that gets these folks to know how much of the change is Q and how much is W, without assuming a legitimate path for an ideal gas. These folks are assuming a process that involves a linear relationship between pressure and volume, a straight line of slope 1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @BobD If the pressure and volume are varying in such a way that the volume is always proportional to the pressure over the entire (presumably reversible) path, then the temperature can always be determined at all points along the path using the ideal gas law; and the cumulative amount of heat added can also be determined at all points along the path.  $P=kV$ where k = 1 atm/liter.  "in such a way that its pressure rises in direct proportion to its volume."

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm just  not seeing this. Are you saying I can draw a line with slope 1 between the initial and final equilibrium states for an ideal gas? See my answer in the OP link at the top. I showed a series of constant pressure and constant volume processes, a "staircase" that follows a constant slope line and that is such that the average work done is the area under the linear relationship, in the limit as the increments of pressure and volume changes are made smaller and smaller. Is that the kind of thing you had in mind?

Comment: @BobD Yes, that is exactly what iI am saying:  you can draw a straight line with slope 1 between the initial and final equilibrium states for the ideal gas (as long as the temperature is also varying in tandem and all the intermediate states are also equilibrium states).

Answer (score 1):

> $W$ is work done on the system. $W=$-405 J

Since the gas expands, work is done *by the system,* not on the system. In order for the sign to be negative, you need to be using the chemist's version of the first law, namely

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$

and not the engineering/physics version of the first law, namely

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

I noticed in the book you are using (pdf 28, pg 18) it is using the chemist version. If you wish to be consistent with the book, and get the correct answer for $Q$ now that @Chet Miller has shown you how to get $\Delta U$, revise your post to use $\Delta U=Q+W$,

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> a) Calculate the work done by on the gas during this process, assuming
>   that there are no other types of work being done.

You have already been told in connection with (a) that pressure cannot rise in direct proportion to volume in the case of an ideal gas. Pressure varies inversely with volume at constant temperature.

There are an infinite number of paths connecting the initial and final state. You cannot determine the work done unless you specify the path or have enough information to determine $\Delta U$ and $Q$ so you can determine $W$ by the first law.

> b) Calculate the change in the helium's energy content during this
>   process.

The change in internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on the temperature change according to

$$\Delta U=mC_{v}\Delta T$$

The only thing you can determine, from the ideal gas law given the initial and final states is the ratio of the final to initial temperature.

$$\frac{P_{1}V_{1}}{T_{1}}=\frac{P_{2}V_{2}}{T_{2}}$$

Since $P_2$=3$P_1$ and $V_2$=3$V_1$,

$$\frac{T_2}{T_1}=9$$

To get the actual temperatures you need either to know either the mass or the number of moles of helium

> c) Calculate the amount of heat added to or removed from helium during
>   this process

Since you have no legitimate information on the path from  1 to 2 and no information from which to compute the change the heat and work transfers. You may assume an initial temperature to the change in internal energy, but per the first law, $\Delta U=Q-W$, it doesn't  tell you which part of the change is heat and which part work. You need more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are misreading the question. It is specified that the expansion is done in such a way that pressure rises in proportion with volume. This will require that heat is added during the process such that temperature rises quadratically with volume. There are unambiguous answers to these questions.

Comment: @Ben51 I am not misreading the question. The questions states the "pressure rises in proportion with  volume". This definitely implies a linear path from 1 to 2 which is not possible for an ideal gas. Look at my answer to the OPs original post. It is a different matter to say that the ratio of pressure to volume is the same at the final state as the original state. That simply defines the equilibrium states, but it does not define the process.  You say the "temperature rises quadratically with volume".

Comment: That is not possible since the ideal gas equation clearly shows that, given the initial and final pressure and volumes, the final temperature has to be 3 times the initial temperature.  Since the final volume is three times the initial volume, the ratio of temperature to volume is one. It is  not a quadratic relationship.

Comment: @BobD - I think that you made an arithmetic mistake between the second and third equations that you wrote down. The initial and final temperatures should differ by a factor of 9, not 3.

Comment: @Samuel Weir Oops you’re right. Thanks

Comment: Your answers are very different from what I got from my university professor. He gave exact answers on all 3 questions. Please check this book on page 32 : http://islamabad-institute.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/1/0/13101414/schroeder_daniel_thermal_physics.pdf

Comment: There are exact answers to all three questions.  You do not need to know the temperature.

Comment: @Ben51 - I'd much appreciate how you get these answers? I've already solved a) and now b) and c) by using Chet Miller's formula. The answers in order are -400 J, 1200J and 1600J.

Comment: I would use this: for an ideal monatomic gas, $U=\frac{3}{2}PV$.  That gives you the answer to (b).  And then you get (c) from $\Delta U=Q-W$.

Comment: @Ben51 Yes, but again, what part of $\Delta U$ is $W$ and what part is $Q$, the other questions. We need a legitimate path from 1 to 2 to determine that. I proposed such a path in my answer to the OP's original post (shown in link).

Comment: I do not understand how the statement of the question leaves any ambiguity as to the path.  It says pressure and volume remain proportional to each other throughout the process.  That defines a path.  Right?

Comment: @Ben51 Per the ideal gas equation, pressure varies inversely with volume, not directly with volume.  $P=\frac{nRT}{V}$. Is this not the  case?

Comment: Assuming isothermal process, yes. That is not the case here.

Comment: @Ben51 Exactly my point. An isothermal process would not get you between the end points. A straight line of slope 1 will get you between the points, but that does not describe a legitimate process for an ideal gas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98512/discussion-between-ben51-and-bob-d).

Comment: @Ben51 OK  Ben, but take a look at my answer to the OP's previous post, if you haven't already. Also it might help if Chet Miller participated (he's a thermo guru, in my opinion).